# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'resize_nearest_neighbor'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I got this error in TS 2.0.

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'resize_nearest_neighbor'

```
 tf.resize_nearest_neighbor(conv3, (tf.shape(conv2)[1], tf.shape(conv2)[2]))
```

Is there an alternative that I can use?

Comment: Please  provide more information than that about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the interpolation method in [`tf.image.resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize):

> The method argument expects an item from the image.ResizeMethod enum, or the string equivalent. The options are:
>
> - nearest: Nearest neighbor interpolation. antialias has no effect when used with nearest neighbor interpolation.
>   tering),

So the equivalent would be

```py
tf.image.resize(conv3, (tf.shape(conv2)[1], tf.shape(conv2)[2]), method='nearest')
```

Note that it can work only if conv3 is a 4-D Tensor of shape [batch, height, width, channels] or a 3-D Tensor of shape [height, width, channels].